# Unsubscribe process on external page with update to _Unsubscribe dataview

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, email, ampscript, soap-api

What I would like to achieve is an email unsubscribe process that is secure, performant and on an external page with the ability to update the internal system table (dataview) _Unsubscribe.

How I imagined this to work is like this:

1. Create an AMPScript variable inside a newsletter that stores the values that are needed for the _Unsubscribe [dataview](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_unsubscribe.htm&type=5) separated by a special character
2. [Encrypt](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/EncryptSymmetric.htm) the variable with AES
3. Create an Unsubscribe Link in the e-mail with a typical a href to our external page and and concat with encrypted variable on it as a parameter value. [First three points shown here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45593/exact-target-customize-unsubscribe-link-in-email)
4. Decrypt the url-parameter with the backend of our external shopengine and store it in different variables (RegEx on special sign)
5. Use the client-id and secret from a package created in the marketing cloud
6. [Retrieve the access token](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-getting-started.meta/mc-getting-started/get-access-token.htm)
7. [Do the last two steps with Java Axis 1.4 or something else](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/choose-programming-lang.htm)
8. Create a [SOAP-API Call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/unsubevent.htm) and insert the values into it
9. Send this data to the right endpoint (which is?) when the user clicks the unsubscribe button in the website

Here my Questions:

- Is this the right way to do it?
- Is there a simpler way when you are using an external page and not cloudpages?
- Is the point 2 secure, what do i have to make sure that point 2 is secure?
- Are there any documents you know that can help me with this task?

Kind regards for reading

Comment: Is this a one click unsub or would this be a click that takes them to a form to unsub?

Comment: Salesforce does not support 3rd party encryption, and support has told me that their encryption methods include a private salt that is unique to each stack, which means using traditional means to encrypt/decrypt AES/DES will fail. I've attempted this and found that to be the case, at least on S1. I was thinking about a workaround to this recently, and here's my thoughts: You'd need to AES Encrypt the SubscriberKey in Salesforce and then post the encrypted value to a data extension which you then retrieve by asking it to decrypt that field in the API call on the Marketing Cloud side

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Logging an unsub event is the way to get unsubscribes logged properly (and ultimately in the `_Unsubscribe` data view).  You can't insert into directly into any of the data views.

You'd need `jobID`, `listID`, `_JobSubscriberBatchID` and an encrypted or obfuscated `_subscriberkey` to replicate what's done on a one-click unsubscribe page.  You may be able to pass and use `SubscriberID` to get around the encryption part, but I haven't tested the API call with that value.

Here's the code in AMPscript.  The SOAP call would use these same objects and methods:

```
%%[

var @debug
var @jid
var @listid
var @batchid
var @email
var @skey
var @reason
var @unsubscribeAll

set @debug = 0
set @jid = AttributeValue("jobid")
set @listid = AttributeValue("listid")
set @batchid = AttributeValue("_JobSubscriberBatchID")
set @email = AttributeValue("emailaddr")
set @skey = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")
set @reason = "One-Click Unsubscribe"
set @unsubscribeAll = RequestParameter("ua")

/* if we know the subscriber */
if not empty(@skey) then

   var @lue
   var @lue_prop
   var @lue_statusCode
   var @overallStatus
   var @requestId
   var @Response
   var @Status
   var @Error

   /* if unsubscribing from all, then set the job, batch and listids to blank, effectively doing a global unsub */
   if @unsubscribeAll == "1" then
     set @jid = ""
     set @listid = ""
     set @batchid = ""
   endif

   /* create a request to inject an unsub event into the LogUnsubEvent platform table */
   set @lue = CreateObject("ExecuteRequest")
   SetObjectProperty(@lue,"Name","LogUnsubEvent")

   /*
    In order to invoke the request, we need to associate the following information with it to define the subscriber context and the job context:

    1. Subscriber Key
    2. JobId associated with the email send
    3. ListID the email was sent to
    4. BatchID the email was sent to
    5. Reason for the unsub
   */

   /* 1. define and associate Subscriber Key to the request */
   set @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
   SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "SubscriberKey")
   SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @skey)
   AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

   /* 2. define and associate JobID to the request */
   if not empty(@jid) then
    set @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "JobID")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @jid)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)
   endif

   /* 3. define and associate ListID to the request */
   if not empty(@listid) then
     set @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
     SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "ListID")
     SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @listid)
     AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)
   endif

   /* 4. define and associate BatchID to the request */
   if not empty(@batchid) then
    set @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "BatchID")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @batchid)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)
   endif

   /* 5. define and associate unsub reason to the request */
   set @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
   SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "Reason")
   SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @reason)
   AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

   /* finally, you invoke the request */
   set @lue_statusCode = InvokeExecute(@lue, @overallStatus, @requestId)

   /* extract messages from the response */
   set @Response = Row(@lue_statusCode, 1)
   set @Status = Field(@Response,"StatusMessage")
   set @Error = Field(@Response,"ErrorCode")

endif

if @debug == 1 then
  output(concat("<br>jid: ", @jid))
  output(concat("<br>listid: ", @listid))
  output(concat("<br>batchid: ", @batchid))
  output(concat("<br>email: ", @email))
  output(concat("<br>skey: ", @skey))
  output(concat("<br>reason: ", @reason))
  output(concat("<br>unsubscribeAll: ", @unsubscribeAll))
  output(concat("<br>overallStatus: ", @overallStatus))
  output(concat("<br>requestId: ", @requestId))
  output(concat("<br>Response: ", @Response))
  output(concat("<br>Status: ", @Status))
  output(concat("<br>Error: ", @Error))
endif

]%%
```

**Reference**

- [Unsubscribe and Log an UnsubEvent with a LogUnsubEvent Execute Call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/unsubscribing_and_logging_an_unsubevent_with_a_logunsubevent_execute_call.htm)

Comment: I tested this and I experienced a behaviour which I do not fully understand. When you do and invoke call with with ua = 0 the values get written to the dataview _Unsubscribe, when  ua = 1 it does not get written to that data_view. When you try to do a ua=0 call and after that a ua=1 call the ua=1 call will error. Is this supposed to be that way? Where can global unsubscribes be found (dataviews etc)? What is the difference between unsubscribing from the all_subscribers list and an global unsubscribe?

Comment: If the system can't tie the unsub back to a particular send job then it's a global unsubscribe.  Details are in the link I added to my answer.

Comment: Hi Adam, i recently stumbled upon this code again and i was asking myself why you attach "reason" to the UnsubEvent. As far as i can see there is no field called reason in the [dataview unsubscribe](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_unsubscribe.htm&type=5). Or is there a field called reason which salesforce forgot to mention?

Comment: It's not in any of the data views, but it is associated with the subscriber in All Subscribers.  Logging an unsub event allows you to set a custom message.

Comment: The UnsubReason is available via Tracking Extract, in the Unsub file.  It's not documented that I can find.  We often extract and import this data (along with NotSent) into Data Extensions.