# Impersonate a Subscriber on a Cloud Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

When a Subscriber clicks on a [CloudPagesURL()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm) link in an email, they are sent to the cloud page with a QueryString (qs) parameter. This tokenized value tells the Cloud Page who the subscriber is, and enables the use of [Personalization Strings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5) such as %%_subscriberkey%% and %%emailaddr%%.

Is there any way to impersonate or replicate this process outside of the CloudPagesURL() in SMFC?

**Example**: To create a personalized "Update my preferences" URL that a Member can access from the "my profile" screen once they have logged in to a website. This link would take them to the SFMC Preference Cloud Page (which would perform as if the member had clicked on a CloudPagesURL link in an Email sent in SFMC).

**Note**: I'm already aware of the "sk" parameter exploit. This can not be part of the solution unless it is protected by other security features to prevent bad actors.

Comment below if you have additional questions and I'll update the question.

Comment: I had a similar use case and I ended up logging the `subscription_center_url` in the SendLog, works great - you can read the whole thread here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/287298/standard-subscription-center-query-string-encoding

Comment: Not a bad solution Zuzan! The problem is that solution requires a Member/Subscriber to have been sent a Logged Email beforehand. Not in my original detail - but in my usecase a Member can create and account and modify their preferences before the "welcome" email has been sent (Race Condition). I've solved this separately by triggering a "Create Subscriber" event; but I still can't solve the QS impersonation perfectly. My current solution is more of an exploit, and I'm hoping someone in the community has a cleaner option :)

Comment: That's true, we have implemented this along with a transactional email to confirm account creation. Are you using a custom pref centre?