# how to redirect to a Marketing cloud profile center by making a custom link

Tags: javascript, ampscript, salesforcedx, marketing-cloud

I want to create a cloud page which needs to be hosted in the Wordpress, the cloud page will take their input as email and when clicked on the submit button it should redirect to their Marketing cloud profile center.I have the query that runs on the data extension for the form and returns the subscriber key, how to use this subscriber key to make a link for the profile center.
I am new to Marketing Cloud, please do let me know if there is a better way to  redirect to marketing cloud Profile Center or if there is no code solution.

Here is the sql query to for returning the subscriber key.

```
SELECT top 1  s.email,c.SubscriberKey
FROM InputDE s
INNER JOIN _Subscribers c ON c.EmailAddress = s.email
order by row_number() over (partition by s.email order by s._customObjectKey desc)
```

Comment: That won't work.. I had a similar requirement and ended up implementing a solution discussed in the comments here, but not sure if this would work for your use case: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/287298/standard-subscription-center-query-string-encoding

Comment: Could you tell me in little brief what ended up working for you, Did you query the subscription URL