# subscriber query string preference page

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, automationstudio, preference-center

is there a way to extract the preference centre query string for each subscriber using a query?

The aim is to pass this string with also the email address and Subscriber key to an external mailing service that will momentarily be used to send newsletters. The custom preference center created in SFMC is therefore intended to be used also for the mails sent using the external mailing service.

Comment: there are more than just subkey required, it required jobid/listid. There is not a way to support your use case.

Comment: I had a similar requirement and ended up implementing a solution discussed in the comments here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/287298/standard-subscription-center-query-string-encoding but honestly not sure if this would work for your use case

Comment: Hold on - you mean custom preference center or the standard one?

Comment: Its custom preference center @zuzannamj