# Record not in unsubscribe data view

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, data-views, unsubscribe

When I query **_Subscribers** I can see a record with a status "unsubscribed"

There is nothing related in the **_Unsubscribe** data view though (I've checked all Business units in the multi org structure)

```
select
s.subscriberKey
,s.Status
,s.DateUnsubscribed
,s.EmailAddress
from _Subscribers as s

join _unsubscribe as u
on s.subscriberid = u.subscriberid

where s.subscriberKey = 'Foo_1'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is this in a child business unit? If yes, try this data view: BusinessUnitUnsubscribes - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_businessunitunsubscribes.htm&type=0

Comment: I can see the event date (few days ago) but cannot find anything related in _Unsubscribe or _BusinessUnitUnsubscribes - would those capture a manual unsubscribe (by a MC admin for instance)

Comment: You can also import a contact that is unsubscribed and you will never find any unsubscribe of that contact. You can still write transactional mails to that contact. So a valid use case

Comment: That's correct @JohannesSchapdick - it is a bit frustrating though that I am not able to track how did that happen for sure

Comment: After investigating this a little bit more I believe the problem was what @JohannesSchapdick said - it was synced from SFDC as unsubscribed already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

_Unsubscribe holds unsubscribe events that are tied to a specific send job. These occur when a subscriber uses an unsubscribe/profile center link from an email or when the LogUnsubEvent API request is made.

_Unsubscribe will not log an event when a subscriber's status is changed due to import, Subscriber update API request, or when changed via UI.

Comment: Was looking up posts on a related topic and wanted to say that there is at least one solution that writes to the _Unsubscribe table via API call...

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/241350/unsubscribe-process-on-external-page-with-update-to-unsubscribe-dataview